# Re-Apply JQuery Chosen to Cloned Elements

Tags: ajax, jquery-chosen

This has a question that has been asked in various forms before, but I cannot find a satisfactory answer so I'd like to ask this quite specifically.

I have a chosen select box which looks like this:

```
<select name="publicationID[]" id="publicationID[]" class="chzn-select-create-option" data-placeholder="Select Publication or type new..." style="width:550px;">
```

which is a slightly modified version of the regular chosen that allows you to add an element to the drop-down list (this isn't relevent to the question).

I have a button which says 'add another publication', which fires off an Ajax query to create a copy of the above element, publicationID[].

The trouble is chosen isn't applying to the clone because of conflicting IDs of the select element. As you can see I'm using the array version of the ID name so that I can iterate through the array after I post the data, but this is no good if the chosen style cannot apply to the copies.

My initial chosen() call is made in the ajax after returning the copy of the element, which normally works fine except in this instance of duplicate IDs:

(The Ajax)

```
document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=oXmlHttp.responseText
doChosen();
```

(The doChosen function)

```
function doChosen() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});
    $(".chzn-select-create-option").chosen({
            create_option: function(term){
            var chosen = this;
            chosen.append_option({
            value: term,
            text: "New: " + term
    });
    },
    persistent_create_option: true
    });
}
```

I have seen a couple of solutions here talking about removing and reapplying the chosen style across the form, but nothing I've seen does this in a simplisic enough manner for me to follow.

Comment: The `name` attribute is used for posting, not the `id`.

Comment: OK, still the same problem though.

Comment: Where in your code do you need the `id`s? They need to be unique and don't think it is going to work like that.

Comment: I don't really care about the IDs, as I'll only be referencing the variable in the POST.

Comment: Where you have the button click event being captured, if you add dochosen(); there, wouldn't that work? Your dochosen() seems to be operating based on the classname so that should worK?

Comment: Did you already fix it? It can work for me. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mvrv/) Chrome and IE10